# Spread Data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to spread a single column in an R dataframe.  I have reviewed many posts on SO, but cant get my solution to work because most solutions seem to require a formula (count, mean, sum, etc).  I am simply looking to spread a column of characters.  For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

school<- c("univ1", "univ2","univ1", "univ2","univ1" )
student<-c('bob', 'sally','ben','trudy','evan')

df <- data.frame(school, student)
```

produces:

```
school            student
univ1             bob
univ2             sally
univ1             ben
univ2             trudy
univ1             evan
```

but what I am trying to output is:

```
school            student1      student2     student2
univ1             bob           ben          evan
univ2             sally         trudy
```

How would I accomplish this?  I tried spread() and pivot_wider() but neither work.  Any thoughts?  The actual dataset is quite large (over 300k rows of data) that will need transposed in this manner if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each group you specify the student number and spread according to that

```
df %>% group_by(school) %>% mutate(n=paste("student",1:n())) %>% spread(n,student)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the student1, student2 and student3 before you use spread(). I'd suggest adding a new column to spread by, for example:

```
df %>%
group_by(school) %>%
mutate(
 student_number = row_number(),
 student_number = str_c("student_", student_number)
) %>%
ungroup() %>%
spread(student_number,student)
```

Comment: I just saw your answer once I posted. Good call

Comment: Great minds think alike and all that :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing this code.  It provides the solution requested, unfortunately I can only choose one correct solution!  Thank you!